# Saving List to XML

Tags: c#, xml, list, load, save

I'm trying to save my list to a XML file so I later can load the data again, if I reopen the program.

This is the code where I try to save the data:

```
public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, string fileName)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\Save.XML", FileMode.Create))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

And I use this code to call the function:

```
Saving.SerializeToXml<List<Vara>>(minaVaror, @"C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\Save.XML");
```

However when I click the button to try and save the data, the program crashes and I'm left with this error/warning:

```
Barline_1.Vara is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.
```

And this is the line of code it's complaning about:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

Any Ideas of what that could be wrong?

Comment: As a site note: what is the use of `fileName` in  `SerializeToXml` ?

Comment: Did you think that the definition of `Barline_1` irrelavant to the question so that you didn't post it?

Answer (score 0):

By definition  XmlSerializer cannot  deserialize  an List or an ArrayList 
From [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
The XmlSerializer cannot deserialize the following: arrays of ArrayList and arrays of List<T>.
```

So you can serialize a List but you cannot deserialize List

So you can use this code to serialize in Xml and deserialize an xml file

```
namespace DataContractSerializerExample
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Xml;

    // You must apply a DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute 
    // to a class to have it serialized by the DataContractSerializer.
     [DataContract(Name = "Vara", Namespace = "http://www.contoso.com")]
   public class Vara
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public double streckKod { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string artNamn { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Test
    {
        private Test() { }

        public static void Main()
        {
            List<Vara> minaVaror = new List<Vara>() { new Vara() { streckKod = 5.0, artNamn = "test1" }, new Vara() { streckKod = 5.0, artNamn = "test2" }, new Vara() { streckKod = 5.0, artNamn = "test3" } };
            string fileName = "test.xml";
            Serialize<List<Vara>>(fileName, minaVaror);
            List<Vara> listDes = Deserialize<List<Vara>>(fileName);  






        }

        public static void Serialize<T>(string fileName,T obj )
        {           
            FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            DataContractSerializer ser =
                new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.WriteObject(writer, obj);
            writer.Close(); 
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,
            FileMode.Open);
            XmlDictionaryReader reader =
                XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));                        
            T  des  =
                (T)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
            reader.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return des;  
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** :
you should  add reference to the 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll